# MySQL/memSQL not using index on BETWEEN join condition

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sqlperformance, singlestore

We have two tables:

- A `dates` table that contains one date per day for the last 10 and next 10 years.
- A `states` table that has the following columns: `start_date`, `end_date`, `state`.

The query we run looks like this:

```
SELECT dates.date, COUNT(*)
FROM dates
JOIN states
ON dates.date BETWEEN states.start_date AND states.end_date
WHERE dates.date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
GROUP BY dates.date
ORDER BY dates.date;
```

According to the query plan, memSQL isn't using an index on the JOIN condition and this makes the query slow. Is there a way we can use an index on the JOIN condition?

We tried memSQL skiplist indexes on dates.date, states.start_date, states.end_date, (states.start_date, states.end_date)

Tables & EXPLAIN:

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `date_index` (`date`)
)

CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `start_date` (`start_date`),
  KEY `end_date` (`end_date`),
  KEY `start_date_end_date` (`start_date`,`end_date`),
)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GatherMerge [remote_0.date] partitions:all est_rows:96 alias:remote_0                                                                               |
| Project [r2.date, CAST(COALESCE($0,0) AS SIGNED) AS `COUNT(*)`] est_rows:96                                                                         |
| Sort [r2.date]                                                                                                                                      |
| HashGroupBy [SUM(r2.`COUNT(*)`) AS $0] groups:[r2.date]                                                                                             |
| TableScan r2 storage:list stream:no                                                                                                                 |
| Repartition [r1.date, `COUNT(*)`] AS r2 shard_key:[date] est_rows:96 est_select_cost:26764032                                                       |
| HashGroupBy [COUNT(*) AS `COUNT(*)`] groups:[r1.date]                                                                                               |
| Filter [r1.date <= states.end_date]                                                                                                                 |
| NestedLoopJoin                                                                                                                                      |
| |---IndexRangeScan drstates_test.states, KEY start_date (start_date) scan:[start_date <= r1.date] est_table_rows:123904 est_filtered:123904         |
| TableScan r1 storage:list stream:no                                                                                                                 |
| Broadcast [dates.date] AS r1 distribution:tree est_rows:96                                                                                          |
| IndexRangeScan drstates_test.dates, KEY date_index (date) scan:[date >= '2017-01-01' AND date <= '2017-01-31'] est_table_rows:18628 est_filtered:96 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAINs and the table declares?

Comment: @Kickstart added.

Comment: You are joining on a DATE against a DATETIME which might be allowing MySQL to ignore the index (and instead favour using the index on the dates in the WHERE clause). If you need the dates table (presume for empty days if you use a LEFT OUTER JOIN) then can you try adding a start and end date time fields and joining on those to avoid the conversion?

Comment: @Kickstart Thanks. I went ahead and created a datetimes table to replace the dates table so that the comparisons happen on the same data type - the output of EXPLAIN looks the same.

Can you explain what you mean by `try adding a start and end date time fields and joining on those to avoid the conversion` ?

It's worth noting that this is not MySQL, but memSQL http://docs.memsql.com/docs.

Comment: Afraid I have no experience of memSQL. However my idea was to add 2 columns to the dates table for the start and end date / time (so for today '2017-04-03 00:00:00' and '2017-03-04 23:59:59' ), with these indexed. Then when joining this against the states table you join using _ON dates.date BETWEEN states.start_datetime AND states.end_datetime_ .

Comment: If you are not using MySQL, remove that tag.

Comment: Why have the `dates` table at all?

Comment: @RickJames - I suspect that is that they want a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and have output containing all dates, whether there are any states records for the dates or not.

Comment: @Kickstart - Probably such a `JOIN` can be done _after_ summarizing the existing data, as I allude to in my Answer.

Comment: @RickJames - Possible, if a sub query is acceptable and that might well be the best solution when dealing with ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
ON dates.date BETWEEN states.start_date
                  AND states.end_date
```

is essentially un-optimizable.  The only practical way to perform this test is to tediously test every row.

If you are using MySQL and don't need the `dates` table, consider starting with

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  states
    WHERE  start_date >= '2017-01-01'
      AND  end_date    < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Note that this works for any combination of `DATE` and `DATETIME` datatypes.

Since I am unclear on the ultimate goal, I am unclear on what to do next.